# Prove that $z_1z_2-2z_3=1$

Tags: complex-numbers

If $|z_1|=|z_2|=|z_3|>0$ and $z_3+z_1z_2,z_2+z_1z_3,z_1+z_2z_3$ are real numbers Prove that $z_1z_2-2z_3=1$

I used the statement that $z$ is real iff $z=\overline{z}$ but it didn't work.

**Edit**:I am sorry I missed the condition that $z_1,z_2,z_3$ are non real complex numbers.

Comment: These conditions are symmetrical and hard to say it is true. See $z_1z_2-2z_3=1$ unless $z_2z_3-2z_1=1$ and $z_1z_3-2z_2=1$ shows all numbers are reals.

Comment: Let $z_j=r(\cos t_j+i\sin t_j);j=1,2,3$

So, we have $$0=\sin t_1+\sin(t_2+t_3)=2\sin\dfrac{t_1+t_2+t_3}2\cos\dfrac{t_2+t_3-t_1}2$$

Similarly, $$\sin\dfrac{t_1+t_2+t_3}2\cos\dfrac{t_1+t_2-t_3}2=0$$

 $$\sin\dfrac{t_1+t_2+t_3}2\cos\dfrac{t_3+t_1-t_2}2=0$$

So, either $\sin\dfrac{t_1+t_2+t_3}2=0\iff\dfrac{t_1+t_2+t_3}2\equiv0\pmod\pi\iff t_1+t_2+t_3\equiv0\pmod{2\pi}$

$z_2z_3=r^2\{\cos(t_2+t_3)+i\sin(t_2+t_3)\}=r^2(\cos t_1-i\sin t_1)=\dfrac{r^3}{z_1}$

Or $$\cos\dfrac{t_1+t_2-t_3}2=\cos\dfrac{t_2+t_3-t_1}2=\cos\dfrac{t_3+t_1-t_2}2=0$$

Comment: $z_1z_2+z_3=R$, real.  If $z_1z_2-2z_3=1$ then $R-1=3z_3$ and hence $z_3$ is real.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z_3+z_1 z_2\in\mathbb R$. 
If $z_1z_2-2z_3\in\mathbb R$, then $$3z_3 = (z_3+z_1 z_2)- (z_1z_2-2z_3) \in\mathbb R.$$ By contraposition, we have that $z_3\not\in\mathbb R$ implies $z_1z_2-2z_3\not\in\mathbb R$ and consequently $z_1z_2-2z_3\neq 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $z_1=r(\cos\alpha+i\sin\alpha)$, $z_2=r(\cos\beta+i\sin\beta)$ and $z_1=r(\cos\gamma+i\sin\gamma)$,

where $\{\alpha,\beta,\gamma\}\subset\left[0^{\circ},360^{\circ}\right)$.

Thus, our conditions give
$$\sin\alpha+r\sin(\beta+\gamma)=0,$$
$$\sin\beta+r\sin(\alpha+\gamma)=0$$ and
$$\sin\gamma+r\sin(\alpha+\beta)=0.$$

Now, let $\prod\limits_{cyc}\sin\alpha\neq0$.

Thus, $$\frac{\sin(\alpha+\beta)}{\sin\gamma}=\frac{\sin(\alpha+\gamma)}{\sin\beta}=\frac{\sin(\beta+\gamma)}{\sin\alpha}=-\frac{1}{r}$$
and from here
$$\cos\alpha-\cos(\alpha+2\beta)=\cos\alpha-\cos(\alpha+2\gamma),$$
which gives
$$\alpha+\beta+\gamma=\pi k$$ or
$$\beta=\gamma+\pi k,$$
where $k\in\mathbb Z$.

1. $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=\pi k$.

We see that it's impossible that $k\in\{0,1,3,5\}$.

Let $k=2$.

Thus, $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=360^{\circ},$ which gives $r=1$ and
$$z_1z_2-2z_3=\cos(\alpha+\beta)+i\sin(\alpha+\beta)-2\cos\gamma-2i\sin\gamma=-\cos\gamma-3i\sin\gamma,$$

which gives a possibility to find a counterexample.